# How to foreach a hasMany relationship in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I'm using Laravel 6 and I want to foreach a hasMany relationship between Layanan Model and Objek Model

**Layanan Model**

```php
class Layanan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['nama_layanan'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'layanans_id';

    public function objeks()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Objek::class);
    }
}
```

**Objek Model**

```php
class Objek extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['layanan_id', 'tipe_objeks'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'objeks_id';

    public function layanan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Layanan::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller.php**

```php
class ObjekController extends Controller
{
    public function object()
    {
        $objek = \App\Objek::all();

        return view('pages.alat.object.object')->with('data', $objek);
    }
}
```

**View**

```php
@foreach ($data as $item)
    @foreach ($item->layanan as $layanan)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $item->objeks_id !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $layanan->layanan_id !!},</td>
            <td>{!! $item->tipe_objeks !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $item->created_at->format('d/m/Y') !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $item->updated_at->format('d/m/Y') !!}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

I get the error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

What did I do wrong? Sometimes, it says that 'layanan' is non-object.

Comment: you are trying to forech in belongsTo that is retrun single instance of table  best to mention relation of 2 table to we can give you right code

Answer (score 0):

```php
class Objek extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'layanan_id', 'tipe_objeks'
    ];
    protected $primaryKey = 'objeks_id';

    public function layanan() {
        return $this->hasMany(Layanan::class,'layanan_id','layanan_id');
    }
}
```

if you put Objek `hasMany` layanan

then only u can loop over 1 row of Objek

like `$data = Objek::find(1(=);`

```php
foreach($data as $layanan)
```

Comment: I got this error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'layanans.objek_objeks_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `layanans` where `layanans`.`objek_objeks_id` = 1 and `layanans`.`objek_objeks_id` is not null)"

Comment: the query that I want to get is "select * from objeks where objeks.layanan_id = layanans.id", but instead, it gives me query like my comment above

Comment: @agastyarimbawa you can give second paramter to found data like i update my code it's may be wrong but you should get an idea

Answer (score 0):

Just update your view as below to add if condition to check wheather relationship values exist for each record.

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
    @if($item->layanan->count())
        @foreach ($item->layanan as $layanan)
            <tr>
                <td>{!! $item->objeks_id !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $layanan->layanan_id !!},</td>
                <td>{!! $item->tipe_objeks !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $item->created_at->format('d/m/Y') !!}</td>
                <td>{!! $item->updated_at->format('d/m/Y') !!}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: sorry for late respond, I've tried the code above, it gives me this error `Call to a member function count() on null `. So that means that there is no relationship done between my Layanan and Objek model?

Comment: Your classes dosn't have correct relationship. You need to rewrite the both relationship functions as 
`public function layanan()
{
 return $this->hasMany(Layanan::class);
}


public function objeks()
{
 return $this->belongsTo(Objek::class);
}`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was exactly what you got. I can't loop collection from hasMany relationship.

I'd solved by converting data into object instead of collection.

```php
public function convertToObject($data) {
    return json_decode(json_encode($data), FALSE);
}
public function object() {
    $objek = \App\Objek::all();
    $objek = $this->convertToObject($objek);

    return view('pages.alat.object.object')->with('data', $objek);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

when you define relationship it will take **id as PK** so good practice define **FK and PK** like below

```
class Layanan extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'nama_layanan'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'layanans_id';

    public function objeks() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Objek', 'layanan_id', 'layanans_id');
    }
}
```

then you need to  use **IF()**

```
@foreach ($data as $item) 
   @if(isset($item->layanan))  ////    @if($item->layanan && is_array($item->layanan))  or   @if(count($item->layanan) > 0)         
   @foreach ($item->layanan as $layanan)

   @endforeach
   @endif
@endforeach
```

**UPDATE**

as per your relationship if you take data from **Objek** then use like this

```
@foreach ($data as $item) 

       <tr>
            <td>{!! $item->objeks_id !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $item->layanan->layanans_id !!},</td>
            <td>{!! $item->tipe_objeks !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $item->created_at->format('d/m/Y') !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $item->updated_at->format('d/m/Y') !!}</td>
        </tr>


@endforeach
```

Comment: I did the code above, it did'nt give me an error, but in my DataTables, it says that I have no data in Objeks Table, meanwhile, I already inserted 2 datas manually in phpmyadmin. What's the problem now? @Hamelraj

Comment: Hey check your relationship  `Layanan -> Objek` `1:N` but you using `$objek = \App\Objek::all();` so confusing ??

Comment: So, what do I need to use instead of ```$objek = \App\Objek::all();```? the logic that comes to my mind when using Objek::all(); is that Model Object (select * from object) is inner joined with Model Layanan.